# How to get exit code from power shell when executing from Control-M

Tags: windows, powershell, control-m

Power shell script return specific exit status, which Control-M is unable to read but exiting with different status. Please let us know how to exit Control-M job with same exit status as returned by power shell script.

Answer (score 2):

`Exit <custom error codes>` will return custom return codes from the script

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that it is often best to call your Power Shell script via a .bat file. E.g.

1. Have a Control-M job that is a "command" and has this in the command field -

C:\Program Files\BMC Software\Control-M Agent\Default\Scripts\PS_log_check.bat

2. The .bat file should then point to your Power Shell script -

powershell -command "& 'C:\Program Files\BMC Software\Control-M Agent\Default\Scripts\PS_log_check.ps1'"